# How to get rid of "Error 4" when running Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have this Makefile that work well:

```
$ cat Makefile
PMD := ~/pmd-bin-6.31.0/bin/run.sh pmd

gen_quality_analysis:
    $(PMD) -d MyCode/ -R rulesets/java/quickstart.xml -f text > quality_analysis/report.txt
$
```

My problem is that I get an `Error 4` from Makefile

```
$ LANG=en make gen_quality_analysis 
~/pmd-bin-6.31.0/bin/run.sh pmd -d AtlasPOC2/ -R rulesets/java/quickstart.xml -f text > quality_analysis/report.txt
Feb 14, 2021 9:53:35 AM net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD encourageToUseIncrementalAnalysis
WARNING: This analysis could be faster, please consider using Incremental Analysis: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.31.0/pmd_userdocs_incremental_analysis.html
make: *** [Makefile:15: gen_quality_analysis] Error 4
$
```

How can I get ride of this

```
make: *** [Makefile:15: gen_quality_analysis] Error 4
```

line ?

Note: despite of the fact I get this error 4 the job work well an I get the expected `report.txt`

Comment: To add to Allan's answer: make invokes a shell to run the script in your recipe.  make can't know what that shell is actually doing.  The only way make knows whether the command run by the shell succeeded or not is by examining the exit code of the shell it invoked.  As is always the case, an exit code of 0 means "success" and any other value is failure.  So, this message from make means that the shell it invoked completed with an exit code of 4, which is not 0, and make assumes that means the command failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of preference:

1. Fix the program `~/pmd-bin-6.31.0/bin/run.sh pmd` to return 0 on success.
2. Write a wrapper that changes the exit status from 4 to 0:

   ```
   $(PMD) -d ...;\
   status=$$?;\
   [ $$status -eq 4 ] && status=0;\
   exit $$status
   ```
3. Ignore errors for that target with `.IGNORE: gen_quality_analysis`.
4. Ignore all errors by running make with `make -i`.

Comment: I think (2) is not really a good suggestion; certainly I wouldn't make it second in order of preference :).  There are other options as well: (A) prefix the command line with `-` so make ignores failures, (B) add extra operations to the recipe, like `|| true`, to ignore the error code.  I would say both of those are better than your #3 or #4 since they impact only one specific command line in the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

From the help documentation of pmd - the return code is 4 when violations are found, and this is expected.
https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cli_reference.html

Add '-failOnViolation false' if you'd like the return code to be 0 even if violations are found.